# How to scrape a table with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the table from this webpage: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics.

When I inspect the webpage, I can see that the structure resembles something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm having trouble finding the table, or any of the contents with BS4.  When I use the following code, the output is simply just 'None'.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('table'))
print(soup.find('tbody'))
print(soup.find('tr'))
print(soup.find('td'))
```

Can anyone help me / give advice on how to solve this problem? 
Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: first print(soup)  , and look it there is not tag table

Comment: like say below ....just need parse the json link https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page makes a xhr request to https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/ and gets the information you see in the table as json.

Comment: Okay thank you. I've never worked with an API before but I'll do some research.

Can I ask, how did you know that this was the issue? Just so I can know for future reference.

Comment: I opened the url with Chrome, enabled developer tools (In the 'More Tools' menu), there you can see several tabs, go to 'Network' and there you'll see all the requests made to load the page, you can filter by type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate that! I've been learning some really useful stuff in these past few days thanks to people like you! :)